# Find all entries for given periode while an entry can start before or end after day but entry-end could be null for an ongoing entry

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a table with lots of entries which I want to query. I want to show the entries overlapping with a certain time span.

Normally I would query the table with

`entry.start <= timespan.end AND entry.end >= timespan.start`

So I would find and display all the edge cases:

```
             |------- time span to query -----|
   |--------------|                 
                                     |----------|
 |-------------------------------------------------|
                      |-----------|
not a result:
x------X
```

But the data model also specifies that the end-time of an entry could be `null`: the entry is ongoing....

So:

```
              |------- time span to query -----|
       |--------------------------------------------------------
                   |-------------------------------------------- 
  
The follwing should not be in the result:
                                                     x----------
```

I'm strugling how to write the correct query to address the null values for the endpoint...

Comment: So, the event starts before the end of the selected timespan, and (either ends after the start of the selected timespan or is null)?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: entry.start <= timespan.end AND (entry.end IS NULL OR entry.end >= timespan.start)

Comment: So, go on then. ;-)

Comment: @JohnMitchell ! NULL must not be consider.  entry.start <= timespan.end AND (entry.end IS NOT NULL AND entry.end >= timespan.start)

Comment: @majidhajibaba Strawberry confirmed with OP that entry.end is either after timespan.start or is null, so I think NULL should be considered as a qualifier. Look closer at the 2nd graph in the question; The first two entries should be returned, their end dates are null. The last entry is not returned, as it starts after the timespan has ended.

Comment: @JohnMitchell. you right. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common range overlapping. General rule - periods starts is less than opposite period ends. If some border may be null which means "infinity" then such border is replaced with its opposite border (if both starts or both ends cannot be null) or with `MIN(start)` or `MAX(end)` over whole table.

In your case (checked timespan range has both borders set always) the condition may be

```
WHERE COALESCE(entry.start, timespan.start) <= timespan.end
  AND COALESCE(entry.end, timespan.end) >= timespan.start
```

If adjacent (but not overlapped) ranges must not be returned then replace `<=` and `>=` with `<` and `>` respectively.